# ActionCable not respecting port assigning in production.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to run my ActionCable server on an alternative port (8080). I set up my `production.rb` as follows:

```
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://my-domain.org:8080/cable'
config.web_socket_server_url = "wss://my-domain.org:8080/cable"
```

The metatags included on the page accurately reflect the changed port:

```
<meta name="action-cable-url" content="wss://my-domain.org:8080/cable" />
```

However, when I inspect the requests, I see that the specified port is NOT included in the URL, so the we can never connect to the websocket:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-domain.org/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I've tested and verified that my server is actively listening on port 8080 for websocket requests, and it's working fine.  If I manually set `App.cable.url = 'wss://my-domain.org:8080/cable'` in javascript, everything works fine.

The problem appears to be that the port specification is not being read by ActionCable from the metatag. How can I resolve this?

Rails 5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Too late but I think the problem is at your cable.js

```
(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});
  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();
}).call(this);
```

- `ActionCable.createConsumer();` Should not have url parameter
- `<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>` Must be defined in your template before JS loads.